# How to get interpolated value for 1D array in LabVIEW?

Tags: arrays, interpolation, labview

I have two 1D arrays that gives an array of points on the XY plane. What I am trying to achieve is to find that `steps` interpolation for which `values` is exactly 0.5. I've tried to solve it using `Interpolate 1D array` and `Threshold 1D array` but no success. The first only returns `values` information for which `steps == 0.5` and the latter is not doing anything apparently, returning 0 always.

I've attached the front panel and block diagram to the post. On the front panel I indicated which information I need.

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here? Because I'm quite stuck with this. Thank you in advance.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos for solving it yourself, but a vi post of the solution would be appreciated for further reference by other people. Here is a solution that uses the 1D interpolation from the mathematics section. One VI, only downside is that you need to convert you interpolation value to an array and the answer back.

[image: Vi Snippet]

[image: Front Panel]

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it. Threshold 1D array vi cannot deal with arrays that contain decreasing values... a rather frustrating error, as I need to transform the array so that the characteristics become increasing to obtain the interpolated value.

From the documentation:

> Note  Use this function only with arrays sorted in non-descending
>   order.